# what is Gpio hog in device tree?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack, device-tree

I am trying to set a pin mode in device tree for am335. I change the pinmux node in device tree as below.

```
pinctrl_test: pinctrl_test_pins {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        0x078 0x07 /* P9_12 OUTPUT | MODE7 | PULLDOWN */
        0x048 0x07 /* P9_14 OUTPUT | MODE7 | PULLDOWN */
    >;
}
```

but I didn't see any changes in `/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e10800.pinmux/pins` .

I found some information about GPIO -HOG , but could not find good documentation.

The Kernel version I am using is 4.8.13

Comment: What is the kernel-image version ?

Comment: I am using 4.8.13 kernel version. I add above-mentioned code in device tree but the mode of GPIO doesn't seem to be changed. Is it necessary to define compatible filed for the node?

Answer (score 13):

After configuring the pinmux to below:

```
pinctrl_test: pinctrl_test_pins {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        0x078 0x07 /* P9_12 OUTPUT | MODE7 | PULLDOWN */
        0x048 0x07 /* P9_14 OUTPUT | MODE7 | PULLDOWN */
    >;
}
```

1. Did you recompile to dtb ?
2. What is the value of 0x44E10848
   and 0x44E10878 in  this file
   /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e10800.pinmux/pins (should be 00000007
   pinctrl-single)

gpio-hog is a gpio node property, which tell the gpio controller to either set the pin to high/low during boot up.

Example to hog a pin high:

```
    gpio@4805b000 {
        compatible = "ti,omap4-gpio";
        reg = <0x4805b000 0x200>;
        interrupts = <0x0 0x1c 0x4>;
        ti,hwmods = "gpio5";
        gpio-controller;
        #gpio-cells = <0x2>;
        interrupt-controller;
        #interrupt-cells = <0x2>;
        status = "okay";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <0xaf>;

        p12 {
            gpio-hog;
            gpios = <0xc 0x0>;
            output-high;
            line-name = "vb4-gpio5-12-gpio";
        };
    };
```

Example to hog a pin low:

```
    gpio@48053000 {
        compatible = "ti,omap4-gpio";
        reg = <0x48053000 0x200>;
        interrupts = <0x0 0x74 0x4>;
        ti,hwmods = "gpio8";
        gpio-controller;
        #gpio-cells = <0x2>;
        interrupt-controller;
        #interrupt-cells = <0x2>;
        status = "okay";

        p0 {
            gpio-hog;
            gpios = <0x0 0x0>;
            output-low;
            line-name = "vb4-gpio8-0-gpio";
        };

    };
```

You can refer more about gpio-hog at [1].

[1] https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt

Comment: Big ups! Been searching for this bit of info for quite a bit and you have put it quite elegantly here.

Comment: Can  this pin later be used by a mux? How to pass it to the "mux-gpios"?

Answer (score 1):

Kernel version 4.8.13 is among the later ones where you dont need device-tree-overlays to change the configuration of a GPIO. You can simply use `congif-pin` utility.

Quoting from [here](https://zeekhuge.me/post/a_handfull_of_commands_and_scripts_to_get_started_with_beagleboneblack/) :

> Config-pin utility - To change the pinmux settings for a pin does not
>   need device tree overlays now (4.4+ kernel), you can simply use
>   ‘config-pin’ utility. To configure the pin you just need to know its
>   position on the board, so to change mux settings of pin at , for
>   example , P8_46
>
> ```
> $ config-pin -l P8_46
> ```
>
> The output shows space separated list of available pin-modes and will
>   look like :
>
> ```
> $ default gpio gpio_pu gpio_pd pruout pruin pwm
> ```
>
> Now to change pinmode, to, for example, pruout
>
> ```
> $ config-pin P8_46 pruout
> ```
>
> This will configure pin at P8_46 to pru_output mode. Further status of
>   the pin can be known using ‘config-pin -i’, which will give detailed
>   output.
>
> ```
> $ config-pin -i P8_46
> Pin name: P8_46
> Function if no cape loaded: hdmi
> Function if cape loaded: default gpio gpio_pu gpio_pd pruout pruin pwm
> Function information: lcd_data1 default gpio2_7 gpio2_7 gpio2_7 pr1_pru1_pru_r30_1 pr1_pru1_pru_r31_1 ehrpwm2B
> Cape: cape-universala cape-univ-hdmi
> Kernel GPIO id: 71
> PRU GPIO id: 103
> ```

Comment: I want to configure pins during boot.

Comment: This is relevant only on beaglebone, this is not a standard ABI that the kernel provides to user-space.